# Absurd bug in my PHP code!

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code in my model class:

```
public function insertPage($owner, $fbPageId = null) {
    echo '<pre> insertPage called </pre>';

    $owner = mysql_escape_string($owner);
    if (!is_null($fbPageId)) {
        echo '<pre>    fbPageId is set </pre>';

        $query = $this->sqlConn->query("INSERT INTO pages XXX");
    } else {
        echo '<pre>    fbPageId is not set </pre>';
        //die('Dummy die()');
        $query = $this->sqlConn->query("INSERT INTO pages XXX");
    }

    return $query;
}
```

(**Notice the Dummy die() because it is important!**)
And then the following code in my controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['fbPageId'])) {
        echo '<pre> fbPageId is set </pre>';
        if (!($page = $this->model->pageExists($_POST['fbPageId']))) { // checks if page exists in db
            echo '<pre> page does not exist </pre>';
            if (!($this->model->insertPage($_SESSION['uid'], $_POST['fbPageId']))) {
                die('Error on INSERT');
            } else {
                echo '<pre> page entered correctly </pre>';
            }
            $pageId = $this->model->lastInsertId();
        } else { // page does exist
            echo '<pre> page does exist </pre>';
            // some other stuff
        }
    }
```

Now: when the controller gets executed I get this output (on an empty table):

```
 fbPageId is set 
 page does not exist 
 insertPage called 
     fbPageId is set 
 page entered correctly
```

Which is exactly what I expect, but when I check into my database instead of just one row containing pageId, facebookId and owner (these are the fields) I get three rows! One is correctly filled with the facebookId and the other ones have a NULL value in it (which I admit in my table).

As you can see I put an echo statement at the start of insertPage() so it should display something everytime it is called, but the string "insertPage called" gets displayed just one time. **Moreover if I uncomment the "Dummy die()" line I get just one rows in my table but the echo statement before it never gets executed!**

I'm freaking out trying to solve this issue.

Comment: there is no such thing as an absurd bug, only absurd code.

Comment: If my code is absurd I'm really willing to change it. I'm new to MVC frameworks so I don't know if what I've done is bad. Was this a general thing or were you specifically referring to my code? I'm here to improve :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get the bold bit -- from the output, the first branch is run -- so the echo statement above the die would never be executed *even if die uncommented*. What happens if only the first branch is in the code? (Comment out the entire 2nd). Are the "XXX" parts correct in both cases?

Comment: If I totally comment out the second branch (which shouldn't be executed anyway) I just get one row. So it's as if the second branch gets executed, but the echo string doesn't get displayed anyway (neither does the "pageInsert called" which should be displayed since it is called inside the second branch). If I put a die() before the query I again get one single row in the database: but this die() shouldn't even be executed in the first place..-

Comment: Also, the XXX things are correct in both cases, I just omitted them to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you're trying to do...this snippet:  `$query = $this->sqlConn->query("INSERT INTO pages XXX");`
you're running it in both conditions, why?

Comment: The queries are different: I have to run different queries based on the null-ness of the $fbPageId variable.

Comment: Well, actually I solved this but I don't even know why this was the reason. The action of the form which posted the data was set to "something/index.php" but in my "framework" every request gets routed through the main index.php so the action should just have been set to "something". Doing so has fixed this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

So in what problem?
Maybe you must try to [flush()](http://php.net/flush) after echo?